# Process Builder and Lookup Table

Tags: process-builder

How can I use process builder to query an unrelated object to obtain a value?

For example, I have a field on the account called Territory__c.  I'd like to query a custom object called Territory__Lookup__c to search for this value and return the id of the record to another field on the account.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use flows along with Process builder if you want to query something like that .

You can invoke flows from the Process Builder